# How to add a column in Student Table. Refer the following schema and add a field – Age Number(2) to the student table

Tags: sql

Refer the following schema and add a field – Age Number(2) to the student table.

[image: Refer the following schema and add a field – Age Number(2) to the student table.]

Comment: Which particular Database?  *(MySQL, Oracle, SQLite, etc?)*  What have you ***tried*** and what specifically did you have an issue with *(show us the code you tried, any error messages, incorrect results, etc)*?  *(Stack Overflow is where you come when what you've tried has failed and you need help on one specific aspect, not where you come to ask someone to do all of the work for you.)*

Comment: The command you are looking for is 'alter table' with sql. This is not a place to just copy and paste homework.

Answer (score 0):

Alter table student add age number(2);